# How to parse xml with simple-xml library ,where data is list and consist of different types of list?

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I  am using simple-xml library to parse xml,where data is list which contains list of different types, data consist of list of images and list of videos,here is xml I represent my java class like this

```
@ElementList(required = false, name = "data")
public ArrayList<Data> data;
public class Data {
public String link;
public String url;}
```

It works ,while I want to map my xml to this class

```
public class Data{
public ArrayList<Image>images;
public ArrayList<Video>videos;}

<data>
      <image>
        <link></link>
        <mask></mask>
      </image>
      <image>
        <link></link>
        <mask></mask>
      </image>
      <video>
        <url></url>
        <mask></mask>
      </video>
      <video>
        <url></url>
        <mask></mask>
      </video> </data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
  @Root
  public class Example {
     @ElementListUnion({
        @ElementList(entry="images", type=Image.class, inline=true),
        @ElementList(entry="videos", type=Vidio.class, inline=true),
     })
     private List<Data> data;
  }
 //vidio
 @Default
  public class Vidio {
    private String link;
    private String mask;
  }
  //image
  @Default
  public class Image {
    private String url;
    private String mask;

  }
```

source : http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php

check the link your self it might help.

Comment: Thanks ,only I don't understand why we need to write these code
@ElementListUnion({
      @ElementL(name="link", type=Image.class),
      @Element(name="mask", type=Vidio.class),
   })
in Video part and 
 @ElementListUnion({
      @Element(name="url", type=Image.class),
      @Element(name="mask", type=Vidio.class),
   }) in Image part

Comment: @A.A.I.A I edit my answer check it now. again this is from the link.

Comment: @A.A.I.A Please aprove my answer as accepted, I need the reputations buddy!